# Projection shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, erdas-imagine

I created a shapefile of Sundarban area Bangladesh. Here it is:

[image]

Here is the projection information about it:

[image]

[image]

I want this shapefile to project upon an image which is here [I downloaded it from earthexplorer USGS where the path and row is 138,45 respectively]
while I was trying to project it using ERDAS software the shapefile does not appear.

Here is the image:

[image]

The image meta data is here:

[image]

and the shapefile metadata is here:

[image] .

Comment: Your shapefile appears to be incorrectly georeferenced. Right now it's about 400 m by 400 m if we assume that the data is projected and just has an incorrect geographic coordinate system assigned to it. Using the raster, you may be able to use the Spatial Adjustment Toolbar to fix it (also assign the coordinate system as suggested by @sarath_srk

Answer (score 0):

Well, From your screenshot it shows the image is in **Projected Coordinate system** and Shape file(Vector) is in **Geographic Coordinate system**.

*First Project your shape file to Projected Coordinate system, Do this*

- Your projection is Datum WGS84, UTM, Zone 45 (EPSG 32645)
- You can search Project tool in Arcmap and Project your data to Projected Coordinate system
- Then use Define Projection tool to set its projection to WGS84 UTM 45

So that your shape file will be projected same as image. Reopen Arcgis and check whether the image and vector data are falling in correct place.

Comment: The coordinate extents are still wrong for UTM 45 North. Compare the values versus the image.

Comment: Look at the EPSG codes. Both have different numbers.. ArcMap shows 4326 while ERDAS Imagine shows 32645

Comment: Yes shape file is in GCS WGS84 (EPSG:4326) and the image is in UTM Zone 45N (EPSG:32645)

Comment: I change the coordinate system as per your suggestion but the boundary file still doesnot show on ERDAS . Do you have any more suggestions ?

Comment: " shape file is in GCS WGS84 (EPSG:4326) and the image is in UTM Zone 45N (EPSG:32645)" - Any ideas how to change this using ARCMAP or ERDAS?

Comment: First you need to correct projection issues using Arcmap and check if it falls in correct location in Arcmap, then proceed with ERDAS. In Arcmap, set data frame projection to UTM 45N and load the shape file and image. If it falls in correct position. Just export shape file with data frame projection in Arcmap.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some cases that the Projection information is correct but the coordinates of actual data extents are wrong. If this is the case, some spatial adjustment is needed. But before that, the image can be reprojected to GCS(lat,long  or EPSG:4326). Then check if shapefile is overlaid on the image.